# Is there a way to bypass escape function in javascript?

Tags: xss

Is there a way to bypass escape function in javascript for exploiting a XSS vulnerability ?

Comment: Related: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/1327/665

Comment: What do you mean by ‘bypassing escape function in JavaScript’?

Comment: If you're asking if there's a way to make the escape() function behave differently from how it is intended then this would likely amount of a browser specific vulnerability

Comment: I don't think you understand what an XSS vulnerability is.  Its not a problem with JavaScript,  its a problem with the server side code.  (Except for dom based xss,  but whatever.)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, lets say you have the following PHP code that is vulnerable to XSS:

```
<?php
print "<script>var t=escape('".$_GET['t']."')</script>";
?>
```

You can supply this file with the following XSS Prof of Concept to get an alert window:

http://localhost/xss.php?t=');alert('xss');//

Answer (score 1):

If you need to override the escape function for whatever reason (I am assuming an already persistent XSS?) I am pretty sure you can override it by creating an anonymious function similar to this:

```
(function() {
   window.escape = function() {
      return true;
  };
})();
```

If however you are looking for general bypassing XSS filters I recommend reading and trying this XSS cheat sheet: http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Comment: `window.escape = encodeURIComponent;`